# How can I say "big brother" or "big sister"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have learned that *fratineto* and *frateto* are used for *little sister* and *little brother*. What about *big sister* and *big brother*? *Fratinego* and *Fratego* sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree that *frat(in)eto* is the only or even the best way to say "little brother/sister." What I say is *(mal)granda frat(in)o.*

A quick check in the Tekstaro (checking only "Zamenhofaj" texts) shows that forms with *granda* are more common, and it seems that forms with *-et-* usually refer to younger siblings who are still small, or it's used as a caress form.

Checking the Tekstaro for adjectives used immediately before "frat-" suggests a few good aleternatives.

- pli juna fratino
- maljuna fratino
- la malgrandan fratinon
- ia malgranda fratino
- viajn plej maljunajn kaj plej junajn fratinojn;
- La plej aĝa frato
- liaj du pli aĝaj fratoj.
- mia malgranda fratino

And even

- mia malgranda frateto

My recomendation - any variation with *aĝa* or *granda* is fine. *Juna* works too.

Answer (score 2):

It is not routine for the concept to be compressed into one word; people generally say *pli aĝa* and *malpli aĝa (pli juna) frat(in)o*.

However, *-eto* and *-ego* do appear in print and they seem perfectly fine to me, a very sensible and appropriate use of those suffixes, particularly if relative age is socially important (e.g. in East Asia). So if you are hunting for a single word then feel free to say *fratego, fratinego*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Estas proverbo *Pliaĝa frato estas dua patro* do *big brother* estas *pliaĝa frato*.

There is a proverb *Pliaĝa frato estas dua patro* (Big brother is second father) so *big brother* is *pliaĝa frato*.

Comment: Is there an Esperanto translation of _Nineteen Eighty-Four_? Would be interesting to see how Big Brother was translated there.

Comment: @OliverMason [There is one](https://cindymckee.com/librejo/Orwell,George-1984.pdf). "Big Brother" is translated as *Granda Frato*, but it doesn't mean that it's a good translation of "big brother" in the sense of "older brother".

Comment: True. It has a different meaning, but I thought it might be interesting to see what option was chosen for that one.